# How to make a pop up window and filled it with product suggestions

Tags: magento-1.8, event-observer

Ideally I want to use Observers when a client presses the buttons "Add to basket" or "Proceed to Checkout" to make a pop up window and make some suggestions on products.
My problem is how can we make a pop up window with magento. Is there a way to make a .phtml and use that as a pop up window?
Or the only way is to do it using jquery. I don't want to change the standard behaviour of the buttons, just to add some suggestions with products from the site.

Comment: Another one that do the same is [www.magebird.com/magento-extensions/popup.html](http://www.magebird.com/magento-extensions/popup.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all create extension in lacal pool.

In layout xml of your extension add  prototype window library call(it is included in magento but is not called).

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem">
        <type>js</type>
        <name>prototype/window.js</name>
    </action>
</reference>
```

After in template where you want to open popup add javascript code

```
function showPopup(sUrl) {
    oPopup = new Window({
        id:'popup_window',
        className: 'magento',
        url: sUrl,
        width: 820,
        height: 600,
        minimizable: false,
        maximizable: false,
        showEffectOptions: {
            duration: 0.4
        },
        hideEffectOptions:{
            duration: 0.4
        },
        destroyOnClose: true
    });
    oPopup.setZIndex(100);
    oPopup.showCenter(true);
}

function closePopup() {
    Windows.close('popup_window');
}
//here assign click event to a tag with href to the content you want to display in popup
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    $$('button selector')[0].observe('click', function(oEvent) {
         showPopup($(this).readAttribute('href'));
     Event.stop(oEvent);
   });
});
```

More information about `Window` object usage you can find [here](http://prototype-window.xilinus.com/).

This is working in [this Captcha extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sitewards-captcha.html). So you can install it and take a look how it works.

Comment: how to call  `closePopup` when user clock on `x` button

Answer (score 4):

Checkout the below code for using magento's inbuilt lightbox and modify it as per requirement. 
**Tried and Tested**

add include below files using layout xml

```
<action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>prototype/window.js</name></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>prototype/windows/themes/default.css</name></action>
<action method="addCss"><name>lib/prototype/windows/themes/magento.css</name></action>
```

below is the prototype function which will invoke the widowbox

```
function showPopup(sUrl) {
    oPopup = new Window({
    id:'popup_window',
    className: 'magento',
    url: sUrl,
    width: 820,
    height: 600,
    minimizable: false,
    maximizable: false,
    showEffectOptions: {
        duration: 0.4
    },
    hideEffectOptions:{
        duration: 0.4
    },
    destroyOnClose: true
    });
    oPopup.setZIndex(100);
    oPopup.showCenter(true);
}

function closePopup() {
    Windows.close('popup_window');
}
```

invoke function using below code

```
$('test_me').observe('click', function(event) {
    showPopup('<?php echo Mage::getUrl("customer/account/login") ?>');
    //Event.stop(oEvent);
});
```